# Joi validation check if record exists in database

Tags: node.js, validation, express, joi

I'm using Joi validation for validating input data,
consider I'm going to create a service and post body is :

```
{"name": "service A", "active": 1, "provider_id": 2}
```

I need to be able to check if in mongodb providers collection, record with id: 2
exists.
is Joi database aware at all ? or should I do sth else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MongoDB, mongoose can be used together with joigoose, which easily converts a Joi schema. Because joi is not a ORM

For ex unique email validation

```
// rating.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const joigoose = require('joigoose')(mongoose)

// Require the 'ratings' schema
const schema = require('./rating-schema')

// Convert joi to mongoose schema
const mongooseSchema = joigoose.convert(schema);

// Modify some fields with database specific instructions 
mongooseSchema.email.unique = true

// Add fields which don't make sense on the schema validator
mongooseSchema.updatedAt = { type: Date, default: Date.now }
mongooseSchema.createdAt = { type: Date, default: Date.now }

// Define mongoose model
const Ratings = mongoose.model('Ratings', mongooseSchema)

module.exports = Ratings
```

Ref: https://codeburst.io/joi-validate-input-and-define-databases-in-javascript-84adc6f1474b
Ref: https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose

Answer (score -1):

joi is simply a JSON validator tool, there is no provision of database connectivity in it.

You can use direct DB query or ORM to check whether record present or not.